# Calling getUnicodeChar method from C++ in Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need unicode value of the key I pressed on Android's soft keyboard on C++ code but it looks like NativeActivity does not expose the 'getUnicodeChar' method. So I tried to call it with JNI but GetMethodID for that function returns '0'. This is my first time with the JNI so I might be doing something very wrong. I guess I have to give my 'AInputEvent' to Java somehow but I'm not sure how. This is the code I wrote:

```
JavaVM* java_vm = and_app->activity->vm; 
JNIEnv* jni_env = and_app->activity->env; 

JavaVMAttachArgs attach_args; 
attach_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; 
attach_args.name = "NativeThread"; 
attach_args.group = NULL; 

jint result = java_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&jni_env, &attach_args); 
if(result == JNI_ERR)
{ 
    return 0;
}

jclass class_key_event = jni_env->FindClass("android.view.KeyEvent");
jmethodID method_get_unicode_char = jni_env->GetMethodID(class_key_event, "getUnicodeChar", "()I");
int return_key = jni_env->CallIntMethod(class_key_event, method_get_unicode_char);
java_vm->DetachCurrentThread();

return return_key;
```

Comment: Just FYI - this solution seems much better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130443/2926815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `FindClass` is quite special, and it requires what [the JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) calls a "a fully-qualified class name", which means a package name with the dots replaced by slashes.

In your case, using:

```
jclass class_key_event = jni_env->FindClass("android/view/KeyEvent");
```

should make your code work, or at least push it in the right direction!

Comment: Based on this, I can get the class_key_event, however, I can't seem to actually convert the AInputEvent in into a jobject sufficient for calling the IntMethod. 
```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x7bc4f3eb00
```