# Onscreen keyboard on Android does not send correct keycodes for second language

Tags: android, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I have the application with NativeActivity.

I wish to show onscreen keyboard and to listen to keys pressed. Everything works fine when I am typing in english, but when I switch keyboard to russian I receive only zeroes for keycode, metastate etc.

To show keyboard I use this code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
View view = activity.getWindow( ).getDecorView( );
imm.showSoftInput( view, 0 );
```

I am receiving keyboard events in onInputEvent function in NativeActivity:

```
int32_t eventType = AInputEvent_getType( event );
if( eventType == AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_KEY )
{
    int32_t keyAction = AKeyEvent_getAction( event );
    int32_t keyCode = AKeyEvent_getKeyCode( event );
    int32_t repeatCount = AKeyEvent_getRepeatCount( event );
    int32_t keyFlags = AKeyEvent_getFlags( event );
    int32_t keyScanCode = AKeyEvent_getScanCode( event );
    int32_t keyMetaState = AKeyEvent_getMetaState( event );

    LOGW( "EventType = AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_KEY, keyAction = %d, keyCode = %d, repeatCount = %d, keyFlags = %d, keyScan = %d, keyMeta = %d", keyAction, keyCode, repeatCount, keyFlags, keyScanCode, keyMetaState );
}
```

And I am getting all event params as zeroes.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) documentation says:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.

Comment: Does it means that I can display the soft keyboard, but I cannot listen to its key events?

Comment: its not 100% guaranteed that you get KeyCodes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I am not asking "how do I get KeyCodes". I am asking "how do I listen to soft keyboard from within NativeActivity". If I cannot rely on KeyEvents or KeyCodes or whatever, what should I do to intercept keyboard clicks?

Comment: What do you meant by NativeActivity ?

Comment: You are not clear. I see you are not the author of this question, If you have any problem post/ask your own question, my answer is intended for the author of this question.

Comment: The very first line of author's question states: "I have the application with NativeActivity."

Comment: and he explained he is getting the `keycodes` but in `zeros`

Comment: And his question is : How can I solve this? I.e. how to listen to keys pressed?

Comment: He want to know whey he is getting zeros, thats what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer (the key is to override `dispatchKeyEvent`):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43871301/674548