# NativeActivity override onKeyDown()

Tags: java, android, native-activity

I having problem with a `NativeActivity` subclass I am working on, my goal would be to catch and handle key events from the Java code instead of
 native code (this is mainly due because this), unfortunately I can not see the `Log()` present in the `onKeyDown` method though the
`onCreate()` log is being printed and the log prints I have placed in the native code are as well. It seems that the `onKeyDown` of my `NativeActivity` subclass is never called.

Any idea?

```
public class CNativeActivity extends NativeActivity{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        private final static String TAG = "CNativeActivity";                                                                                                                            

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                                                                                  
            Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");                                                                                                                                                          
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                                    

        @Override                                                                                                                                                                            
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {                                                                                                                              
            Log.v(TAG, "onKeyDown");                                                                                                                                                          
            return true;                                                                                                                                                                      
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063164/logcat-not-showing-debug-level-messages

Comment: That does not seem to be my problem, unfortunately, thank you anyawy

Answer (score 0):

add  implements KeyEvent.Callback

```
public class @activity@ extends NativeActivity implements KeyEvent.Callback  {
   public boolean onKeyMultiple (int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event)
}
```

KeyEvent.Callback overrides happen after the native AInputEvent dispatching though; so basically you'll have to ignore all old dipatching and implement something new if you want to get the extended keys like  ÷,√,€,£, …